# pip - fatal error: leveldb/db.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, debian, python3, pip

The usual answer to this is that I am missing leveldb from my system, however the `python3-leveldb` `libleveldb-dev` packages includede in Debian 9 are for python3.5 but I am using python3.7

I compiled python 3.7 following this guide (with pip support) https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/06/30/building-python-ubuntu-wsl-debian/ and when I try to install the `plyvel` package as such: `pip3.7 install plyvel` I get the error below, emphasis is on leveldb/db.h missing `gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c plyvel/_plyvel.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/plyvel/_plyvel.o -Wall -g
    plyvel/_plyvel.cpp:589:24: fatal error: leveldb/db.h: No such file or directory
     #include "leveldb/db.h"`

I have already installed leveldb using pip3.7, when checking if it is installed I get back: `dRequirement already satisfied: leveldb in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.194)`

Answer (score 2):

Install the leveldb dependency for plyvel using the system package manager before installing plyvel with pip:

```
sudo apt-get install libleveldb-dev
```